# Conditional if is category on category.php and single.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I´m trying to make a conditional that shows only content if the user is in a specific category or a single.php that belongs to that category. I have tried using these codes but both doesn´t work:

```
<?php if (in_category('catering')) : ?> 
<div class='eventinfo'> 
    <h2>Event Details</h2>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and this one:

```
<?php if(is_category('catering')){

<h2>text</h2>

} endif ?>
```

It just doesn´t seem to do anything, any ideas how could it be the conditional?

Also I need to put it in the category.php and the single.php so it shows also the content when on a single post that belongs to the category.

Comment: have you tried http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <?php if(is_category('catering')){?>

    <h2>text</h2>

<?php }  ?>


<?php if (in_category('catering')) { ?> 
<div class='eventinfo'> 
    <h2>Event Details</h2>
</div>
<?php} ?>
```

Comment: this works only on the category.php file, not on the single.php :(

Comment: check the answer do you want this ?